# UIAlertView: UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput: Numeric keyboard

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm currently using this UIAlertView to do a login popup,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restricted"
                                                message:@"Please Enter Code to Enable Fields" 
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Login"
                      , nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;

[alert show];
```

However I would like the text input to be a numeric keyboard instead of the regular keyboard

Is there a easy way to do this, or do I have to look into creating a custom UIAleartView

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try this to change the keyboard type of the `UIAlertView`'s field:

```
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: add <UITextFieldDelegate> to your *.h file

Answer (score 4):

Cool answer but for iOS 7 I have a little adaptation

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Changing the keyboard before calling `[alert show];` should alleviate the need to resign and become first responder.

Answer (score 3):

```
 UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter File Number" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        alertView1.alertViewStyle = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
        myTextField = [alertView1 textFieldAtIndex:0];
        myTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        [alertView1 setTag:3];
        [alertView1 show];
```