# Change type of UIAlertView keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uialertview

How do I specify that my keyboard for the `UIAlertView` text field is to be a number pad keyboard?  I am setting `alertViewStyle` to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`.

Comment: The title is a little too broad.  Also this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579658/uialertview-uialertviewstylesecuretextinput-numeric-keyboard

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
UITextField* tf = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

See the [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) and [UITextInputTraits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html) docs

Comment: Thanks. I checked the docs. I ended up using [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];