# AlertIOS.prompt for numerical input

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing an application in which I have to ask the user for some numerical input. In order to achieve that, I've thought of AlertIOS.prompt, but the problem is that the keyboard types are for some reason limited to 'plain-text', 'secure-text' or 'login-password' (I would like something like `TextInput`'s 'numeric'). Is there an alternative which would provide the same native look to a alert box? I've also tried `<Modal/>`, but it does not feel as native as AlertIOS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS only supports these [input styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertViewStyle) by default. If you have a bit of Obj-C experience you could try [changing the keyboard yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579935/1783214).

Comment: Mmm I think I will give it a try, thanks for the tip!